# escaping a single dot with double backslash - awk

Tags: regular-expression, awk

"effective awk programming" book has an example on Field-Splitting. here is the example:

> If you want fields to be separated by a literal period
>   followed by any single character, use `‘FS = "\\.."’`.

Why it is double backslash? shouldn’t it be `\..`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Both string and regular expressions in [awk](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) share many of the same backslash escapes, including `\\` for a single `\`.  Since `FS` is a string value that is internally interpreted as a regular expression, those shared escapes have to be escaped twice.  Thus `\\` in a string becomes `\` by the time it is interpreted as a regular expression.