# How can I use a bash variable as a regex argument to gsub() and match()?

Tags: text-processing, awk, regular-expression, variable

I have a script

```
#! /bin/bash
awk -v pat="$1" '{ if(match($0, pat)) {print $0} }' "$3"
awk -v pat="$1" -v rep="$2" '{gsub(pat, rep); print $0}' "$3"
```

I would like to run it  like

```
myscript '\.\.+' ' ' ./inputfile
```

where `$1` is supposed to be a regex understandable by `awk` (GNU awk).

Specifying `pat` as a regex expression as arguments to `gsub()` and `match()` will not work. I was wondering how I can make it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re going about things correctly, as far as passing variables is concerned. To make the expression work you need to [double the backslashes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37747/86440), [at least with Gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Gory-Details.html):

```
myscript '\\.\\.+' ' ' ./inputfile
```

Note that you can simplify the AWK parts:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v pat="$1" 'match($0, pat)' "$3"
awk -v pat="$1" -v rep="$2" '{gsub(pat, rep)} 1' "$3"
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes my typo. (1) Could you explain the reason of doubling backslash?  Is it correct that bash will remove the backslash in `$1` in `awk -v pat="$1"`?  Does it work if gsub() sees the pattern argument without any backslash? Does gsub() not require its pattern argument to be enclosed in `/.../`? (2) Is it possible to write  a bash script, so that I can just specify a regex as an argument to the script in the same way as I specify it to awk directly?

Comment: Sorry, ignore partially my (1). I was thinking of something else. I need to specify literal dot to awk, so I need literal backslash to escape it.

Comment: (1) See the link in my updated answer re the double backslashes. Bash doesn’t remove the backslash, but AWK needs two because it processes them twice. `gsub()` doesn’t need `/.../`. (2) You could double the backslashes before calling AWK...

Comment: Also: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Gory-Details.html

Comment: notice that the behavior wrt. `"\."` is different between `gawk` and `mawk` (the default on debian); ex. `echo foo.bar | awk '{gsub("\.","X")}1'` will print different things depending on which `awk` was used. The values of variables set on the command line are treated exactly as if they were enclosed in `"`, and the standard leaves the behavior of awk wrt. non-standard escapes (other than `\n`,`\t`, etc) undefined.

Comment: @mosvy yeah I realised that too while testing ;-).

Comment: @glennjackman that link is for replacement strings, instead of regex, although both are in similar situation in relation to gawk.

Comment: Thanks. Related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/481610/how-are-backslashes-processed-succesively-by-bash-gawk-and-gensub

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick answer with a different approach : script written in Awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN { find=ARGV[1]; repl=ARGV[2]; delete ARGV[1]; delete ARGV[2]}
      { print gensub(find,repl,"g",$0) }
```

and then the usual Unix filter behavior:

```
$ chmod 755 myawkscript

$ ls |myawkscript '\w(.)' '{\1}'
{y}{w}{s}{r}{p}t

$ myawkscript '(\w+)' '{\1}' myawkscript 
#!/{usr}/{bin}/{gawk} -{f}
{BEGIN} { {find}={ARGV}[{1}]; {repl}={ARGV}[{2}]; ..... 
      { {print} {gensub}({find},{repl},"{g}",${0}) }
```