# How are backslashes processed succesively by bash, gawk and gensub()?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file

```
$ cat f2
line 1; li
ne 2$
```

where note that the last `$` is bash prompt, not part of the file content.

I try to [concatenate each line which doesn't end in a digit with its next line with gawk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/481498/674). But unlike my previous post, now I try to figure out how backslashes are handled by bash, gawk and gensub(), by experimenting with different number of backslashes in front of the new line character `\n`. I was wondering why gawk commands with more than three backslashes before `n` fail to find a line not ending in a digit, and succeed when otherwise?
Generally, how are backslashes processed succesively by bash, gawk and gensub()? Thanks.

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{RS="\f"} {b=gensub("([^[:digit:] ]) *\n", "\\1", "g"); print b}' f2
line 1; line 2
$ gawk 'BEGIN{RS="\f"} {b=gensub("([^[:digit:] ]) *\\n", "\\1", "g"); print b}' f2
line 1; line 2
$ gawk 'BEGIN{RS="\f"} {b=gensub("([^[:digit:] ]) *\\\n", "\\1", "g"); print b}' f2
line 1; line 2
$ gawk 'BEGIN{RS="\f"} {b=gensub("([^[:digit:] ]) *\\\\n", "\\1", "g"); print b}' f2
line 1; li
ne 2
```

Can someone explain what gawk and gensub() see when `\n`, `\\n`, `\\\n`, and `\\\\n` pass through bash and gawk respectively?

Take  `\n` as example, does bash not modify it (because of single quotes in bash) so gawk sees `\n`? Does gawk modify `\n` to be `n` so gensub() sees `n`,  and if yes, why can gensub() know it is a newline to match?

Comment: Regarding the bash part, if you're using single quotes (`'...'`) then everything including backspaces are preserved as is, so they're all passed down to gawk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bash`, `'...'` are strong quotes, so with `'\n'`, a literal `\n` is passed to `awk` and with `'\\n'`, a literal `\\n`. There's no transformation.

In `awk`, inside `"..."`, `\n` and `\\`... are expanded. So when passed `"\n"` to `gensub()` (or `print` or anything in `awk`), that's an actual newline character, and when passed `"\\"`, that's a `\`.

Now, `gensub()` also understands its first argument as a regular expression, where `\` also has a special meaning which varies between implementations.

What is consistent between implementations is that a `\\` regexp matches a literal `\` just like `\.` matches a literal `.`. However for a `\n` regexp, whether that matches a newline character or a `n` varies with the implementation. In the case of `gawk`, that matches on newline. So both `gensub("\n", "x")` and `gensub("\\n", "x")` replace newline characters with `x`, the first one because a literal newline character is passed to `gensub()`, the second because `\n` is passed to `gensub()` which is understood as a regexp that matches a newline character.

Note that the POSIX specification used to have several issues when it came to backslash processing in regular expressions in `awk`. That will be corrected in the next version of the specification. See http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1105 for details.

It gets even more confused when using `/\n/` instead of `"\n"`.

Comment: Thanks. I seem to remember you have posted some shell commands for automatically double backslashes in a string (possibly for the same purpose). Do you happen to remember whether and where you have posted it?